# How to correctly setup auxiliary routes in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ionic4

I'm having an issue with routing in Angular 6. My app has a side menu on the right side, that updates as users navigate on the left-hand side of the page. This side menu doesn't show on the `user-dashboard` where the users projects are listed. It needs to show when the user selects a project and thus navigates to the `project-home`.

The organization can be seen in the image below. Once the user gets to `project-home` they should see the master/detail flow from `elements-list` to `element-detail` on the left-hand-side. Independently, under `activities` on the right-hand-side, a user should be able to click through the tabs for `images`, `notes`, and `tasks`.

**Update:**
Here is a Stackblitz illustrating the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zsoflin-routing

I'm at a loss, and would appreciate any direction on how to structure my routes. Thank you.
-Zach

[image: Map]

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
`
const routes: Routes =[
  { path: 'user-dashboard', component: UserDashboard },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'project/:projectId',
    component: ProjectHomePage, 
    children:[
        {path: '', component: ElementsPage, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'element/:elementId', component: ElementPage, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'edit/:categoryId', component: EditFormPage, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'act', component:ActivitiesPage, 
            children: [
                {path:'images',outlet:'images',component: ImagesPage},
                {path:'notes',outlet:'notes',component: NotesPage},
                {path:'tasks',outlet:'tasks',component: TasksPage}
            ]
        },
    ]
  }
]
`
```

**project-home.page.html**

```
<ion-split-pane when="md">
<ion-menu type="push" menu-id="activityMenu" side="end" id="menucontent">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="act"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
```

**activities.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs style="margin-top:56px;">
  <ion-tab label="Images" href="(images:images)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="images"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Notes" href="/tabs/(notes:notes)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="notes"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Tasks"" href="/tabs/(tasks:tasks)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="tasks"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

AppModule:

```
const routes: Routes =[
  { path: 'user-dashboard', component: UserDashboard },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'user-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'project',
    loadChildren: 'path.to.this.module#ProjectModule'
  }
];
```

ProjectModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: 'ElementsPage' // If you really want the ProjectHomePage place here
  },
  {
    path: ':elementId',
    component: ElementPage
  },
  {
    path: ':categoryId/edit', // or 'edit/:categoryId'
    component: EditFormPage
  },
  {
    path: 'act',
    loadChildren: 'path.to.this.module#ActivityModule'
  }
];
```

ActivityModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'images', outlet:'images', component: ImagesPage },
  { path:'notes', outlet:'notes', component: NotesPage },
  { path:'tasks', outlet:'tasks', component: TasksPage }
];
```

**Update:** Your routes is working fine, you need now to route your outlet. Put your outlets nested your `AppModule` and in you **app.component.ts** you call:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { outletName: ['navigatingPath'] } }]);
  }
```

Them your outlets will show in like a popup. For more info how to do it, [here is the main guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets).

If you are trying to adding a sub menu in the right side, this is a strutural page called `sidenav`. I suggest you to add it in the main tree and show/hide when needed. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp), [here](https://www.devglan.com/angular/material-sidenav-example) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sidebar)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I changed things around as you suggested but still having issue with my activities side-menu showing. I suspect it has to do with how I am using ion-router-outlet shown above (project-home.page.html). How do I display the 'act' route as the side-menu?

Comment: Try putting the empty path from root route to redirect to act ActivityModule to se if is your navigation

Comment: Ok, I tried this. It throw an error because it says that redirectTo and component cannot be used on the same route. Also, If I navigate to /act it just loads that view in the left-hand side, not the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Put your example in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) project them we can help you more

Comment: Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/zsoflin-routing I think I'm close to getting it working. The issue I'm having now is that i want the right-hand side to navigate independently, regardless of where I am at on the left-hand side. Currently, when in the element-detail on the left-hand side, navigating the tabs in the right-hand side brings the left-hand side back to element-list.

Comment: For example, I can successfully visit the following url: https://zsoflin-routing.stackblitz.io/project/1234/(images:images)     but, I cannot successfully visit this url: https://zsoflin-routing.stackblitz.io/project/1234/element/abc/(images:images)

Comment: any thoughts on this? I'm kind of at a stand still.

Comment: Oh! no I didn't sorry. I'll take a look. Thank you!

Comment: It's ok. In other application I use [AdminLTE template](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) it have a nice `sidebar` and a great `top navbar`

Comment: Not sure if you can put this template in ionic